# QSettings iniFormat

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am trying to create an ini file from my application (Qt5.9.6):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QSettings>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QSettings settings(QStringLiteral("C:\\test.ini"), QSettings::IniFormat);
    settings.setValue(QStringLiteral("global/mykey"), 1234);
    settings.sync();
    app.exec();
}
```

The file is created, however the content is not what I expect:

```
[global]
mykey="\x1\x1\x1\x1"
```

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. Are you sure you don't overwrite the value somewhere else.

Comment: @chehrlic: Yes I am pretty sure. Although at some point in the code I do read from another .ini file into another QSettings instance. I guess it shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, compilable example where you show the problem. It works fine here.

Comment: @chehrlic: I created a minimal example, got the same output.

Comment: I can't reproduce it with Qt5.15 on linux and windows.
What does 'qDebug() << "value:" << settings.value("global/mykey").toInt();' after settings.sync() prints out?

Comment: @chehrlic: It prints the correct value. Maybe it's something with the writing of the values into the file. I have also tried setting the iniCodec, but no matter what I set, I got the same result every time. I will look into the Qt's code on Monday.

Comment: Please only read the value from the file - \x1\x1\x1\x1 can not decode to 1234 in any encoding.

Comment: @chehrlic We tracked down the issue, one of my collegues put a bug into our custom Qt code. Instead of checking for equality he used the assigment operator, that's why it printed only \x1. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a bug introduced by a colleage into our custom built Qt library.